# Chrome Extension: Pulling data in background and store in DB

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to pull data from a remote URL, which is not currently visible and store information periodically on a local SQLite Db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can call a remote URL and fetch data with [XHR](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)
2. Storing it on local SQLite DB isn't possible because you are bound inside chrome runtime and you can't connect to SQLite database from browser, instead you can use native WebSQL or IndexedDB in chrome itself and store data in it.

Comment: Can I have a kind of some way to create Table in it with some client if using IndexDB?

Comment: you can use object store https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB

Comment: it seems it's not SQL based. Is there any SQL alternative available?

Comment: There is web SQL as well https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database
 http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm

Comment: I'd need to call that script in background page?